# Turn off autohide feature of GNOME shell bottom panel

Tags: gnome-shell

This one is specific to Gnome shell 3. I like bottom panel of GNOME Shell, but its autohide feature is a turn-offs. There are a lots of extensions out there, but none provides this facility.
You can help me by pointing to the right extension. 
(I am going through this
https://live.gnome.org/GnomeShell/Extensions/StepByStepTutorial/
 tutorial but I cannot say if I can finish working on this.

Comment: did you find a solution or did the behaviour change with upgrades?